# Using Entity Framework to Call an Oracle Stored Procedure with Multiple Cursors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle

I wrote the following code to use Entity Framework 6 and Managed Oracle Providers to call an Oracle stored procedure that returns multiple cursors.

Would like some input about the code I used to open and close the database connection. Please note that the open and close code is a workaround for a possible bug in the Oracle library that occurs every time `using` is used. Doing that *instead* of the workaround would throw the following exception:

```
 System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'OracleConnection'.'
```

Would also like some input on the way I am getting the multiple cursors and whether or not there might be a better way.

**Working Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace MyCompany
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext();

        public MyItems GetMyItems(string id)
        {
            var sqlQuery = "";
            var oracleParameters = new List<OracleParameter>();
            var oneEntityList = new List<OneEntity>();
            var twoEntityList = new List<TwoEntity>();
            var threeEntityList = new List<ThreeEntity>();

            sqlQuery = @"

BEGIN 

MY_PACKAGE.GetMyItems(:id, :p_cursor1, :p_cursor2, :p_cursor3);

END;

";
            oracleParameters = new List<OracleParameter>
            {
                new OracleParameter("p_id", id),
                new OracleParameter("p_cursor1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output),
                new OracleParameter("p_cursor2", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output),
                new OracleParameter("p_cursor3", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output)
            };

            var connection = dbContext.Database.Connection;            
            connection.Open();
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(oracleParameters.ToArray());
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                oneEntityList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
                                                                            .Translate<OneEntity>(reader)
                                                                            .ToList();
                reader.NextResult();

                twoEntityList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
                                                                            .Translate<TwoEntity>(reader)
                                                                            .ToList();
                reader.NextResult();

                threeEntityList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
                                                                            .Translate<ThreeEntity>(reader)
                                                                            .ToList();
            }
            connection.Close();

            return new MyItems { OneEntity = oneEntityList, TwoEntity = twoEntityList, ThreeEntity = threeEntityList };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience EF and Oracle don't like each other. EF is great only for the sql server. With oracle it's easier to use Dapper and raw queries.

Comment: It appears that [you removed the error](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/208312/3) “`System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'OracleConnection'.'`” from the description, yet didn’t change the code. Does the error still occur?

Comment: No, the error does not occur. There never was an error on the code I posted. I was mentioning that if I used a using statement an error occurred. This code review post is legit and should not be on hold.

Comment: _This code review post is legit_ - I think it could be if you reframed it because 1000% the first suggestion will be to use the `using` statement to which you will replay that it doesn't work because an exception is thrown... this is a vicious circle. You've removed a very important fact from your question. Please clarify that this is a **workaround** for the apparent bug in the Oracle library that occurs everytime `using` is used and it throws the exception you've named in the first version.

Comment: @t3chb0t Updated post. I did not realize the exception was a bug with Oracle.

Comment: I think the dispose problem relates to the fact, that you've tried to dispose a Connection owned by dbContext which is an instance member of `MyClass`. You should make your `MyClass` implement `IDisposable` and then dispose the dbContext in `MyClass.Dispose()` instead. That will dispose the connection properly when `dbContext` is disposed.